# How to use Html.TextAreaFor using many Ajax.BeginForms in same view

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-validation, ajax.beginform

I'm not sure about how to ask my question, so I'll show my screen.

[image]

I have a control for subscriptions in a page. The context of the page inst to post data, so the model is some kind of "read-only". My model has the inscriptions (left site), the inviteds (second tab of left side) and the approveds (right side). The green buttons, turn the current item as approved (send it to right side by ajax, removing the html from the left panel and inserting in the right panel). The red buttons (remover) do the opposite, unapproving the user.

Ok, until now I was just trying to explaining the picture. Now, my real problem.

Every m is a button. It opens a messagebox like the 2nd item on the right panel shows. The m turn into ^ to close the accordion.*
My problem is: I'm using a Ajax.BeginForm in those textarea + submit button but without model binder. I'm using

```
@Html.TextArea("message")
```

instead

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m=>m.Message)
```

because my view model, like a said before, has another context. Now, I really dont know the right approach to do that. I want the jquery validation unobstrusive to work with this textarea. I was thinking about use a @Html.RenderAction for each partial with messagebox, but I'm worried about performance. There is any kind of help me with that?
Doesnt matter if takes longer, I'm looking for the right stuff.

Thanks

*the + sign, m and ^ will be changed by nice icons later.

Comment: could you please provide code for the view and for action method?

Comment: What do you mean by *another context*?

Comment: @Justin the page is here to display all the users subscriptions. For each subscription, I can send a message to the user about something to change (if his subscription is wrong), so the user can fix it to be approved. The model is for the model with the Subscriptions (ChampionshipModel). Did I explained?

Comment: @SergeyBoiko the view is separated in many partials. Its too big and have a lot of other stuffs. Can I post a piece of something for you? What is better?

Answer (score 0):

If the model for this page has another context make up another page with the right context and let it pop up in an iframe...

From your screenshot I would assume that this is about programming of the last 10%. The concept of approval has a 'lesser-reject-nature': People that give away something for approval typically try to follow the rules to allow a fluent approval. As soon as you articulate the approval rules clearly any need to respond with messages becomes a minor issue.

Answer (score 0):

> "because my view model, like a said before, has another context..."

You're in control of the view model? Why not arrange it so it properly fits the view, and map your data to it. Then you would be able to use the strong typed html helper.

Otherwise, consider rendering a partial view.  You can then redefine the @model type for the partial, it could be a property of you main view's model, and use the Html helper on that.